# mongo devide every field

Tags: jquery, mongodb

How do I divide a field by a factor of 100 in every mongo document in a collection.

For example if  I have documents

```
{
"item":"Shoe",
"cost":100
}
{
"item":"tie",
"cost":1000
}
```

How do I update every item cost devided by a factor of 100

so far I have

```
db.Usage.update({ }, {$set : {'cost': 'cost'/100}}, false, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to find() each indidivual document and update() each document with the new value using the $set operator.

You *can not* perform such an update using *one* update() operation.